# Parse RFC 822 date (and make timezones work)

Tags: dart

Just realized `DateFormat` is not caring about the time zone field. The two prints below will both output the same time.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var formatter = DateFormat('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz');

  print(formatter.parse('Tue, 9 Jun 2020 19:46:10 +0000'));
  print(formatter.parse('Tue, 9 Jun 2020 19:46:10 +0200'));
}
```

Sadly, I can't use `DateTime.parse` instead as it only accepts ISO-8601 strings.

So that begs the question, how do I parse RFC 822 timestamps correctly in Dart?

Comment: I think that you would need to use a regexp to split the timestamp string, parse the part without the timezone with `DateFormat`, parse the timezone offset yourself, and then combine them into a new `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. Added an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per jamesdin's comment, I couldn't find any other way than to do this manually. Ended up with:

```
const MONTHS = {
  'Jan': '01',
  'Feb': '02',
  'Mar': '03',
  'Apr': '04',
  'May': '05',
  'Jun': '06',
  'Jul': '07',
  'Aug': '08',
  'Sep': '09',
  'Oct': '10',
  'Nov': '11',
  'Dec': '12',
};

DateTime parseRfc822(String input) {
  var splits = input.split(' ');
  var reformatted = splits[3] +
      '-' +
      MONTHS[splits[2]] +
      '-' +
      (splits[1].length == 1 ? '0' + splits[1] : splits[1]) +
      ' ' +
      splits[4] +
      ' ' +
      splits[5];

  return DateTime.tryParse(reformatted);
}
```

Comment: I'd use something like `RegExp(r'^(?<datetime>.+) (?<offset>[+-]\d{4})$')` to extract the offset and everything *but* the offset, and then use `DateTime.tryParse` or `DateFormat.parse` on the latter.

Comment: I would add `input = input.replaceFirst('GMT', '+0000');` to process [standard RFC 822 format](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html) like `Sat, 07 Sep 2002 9:42:31 GMT`.

Answer (score 0):

While the code has more lines, I find this to be more readable. I hope this helps someone in understanding and use.

```dart
const _MONTHS = {
  'Jan': '01',
  'Feb': '02',
  'Mar': '03',
  'Apr': '04',
  'May': '05',
  'Jun': '06',
  'Jul': '07',
  'Aug': '08',
  'Sep': '09',
  'Oct': '10',
  'Nov': '11',
  'Dec': '12',
};

DateTime? parseRfc822(String input) {
  input = input.replaceFirst('GMT', '+0000');

  final splits = input.split(' ');

  final splitYear = splits[3];

  final splitMonth = _MONTHS[splits[2]];
  if (splitMonth == null) return null;

  var splitDay = splits[1];
  if (splitDay.length == 1) {
    splitDay = '0$splitDay';
  }

  final splitTime = splits[4], splitZone = splits[5];

  var reformatted = '$splitYear-$splitMonth-$splitDay $splitTime $splitZone';

  return DateTime.tryParse(reformatted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution, which utilizes converters.

```dart
class Rfc822ToDateTimeConverter extends Converter<String, DateTime> {
  @override
  DateTime convert(String input) {
    final segments = input.split(' ');

    final day = int.parse(segments[1]);
    final month = _parseMonth(segments[2]);
    final year = int.parse(segments[3]);
    final (hour, minute, second) = _parseHour(segments[4]);
    final (isTzAddition, tzDuration) = _parseTzVal(segments[5]);

    final dtAgnostic = DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
    final DateTime dtResolved;

    if (isTzAddition) {
      dtResolved = dtAgnostic.subtract(tzDuration);
    } else {
      dtResolved = dtAgnostic.add(tzDuration);
    }

    return dtResolved;
  }

  int _parseMonth(String input) {
    const months = {
      'Jan': 1,
      'Feb': 2,
      'Mar': 3,
      'Apr': 4,
      'May': 5,
      'Jun': 6,
      'Jul': 7,
      'Aug': 8,
      'Sep': 9,
      'Oct': 10,
      'Nov': 11,
      'Dec': 12,
    };

    return months[input]!;
  }

  (int, int, int) _parseHour(String input) {
    final segments = input.split(':');
    return (
      int.parse(segments[0]),
      int.parse(segments[1]),
      int.parse(segments[2]),
    );
  }

  (bool, Duration) _parseTzVal(String input) {
    if (input == 'GMT') {
      return (true, Duration.zero);
    }

    final hoursStr = input.substring(1, 3);
    final minutesStr = input.substring(3, 5);
    final hours = int.parse(hoursStr);
    final minutes = int.parse(minutesStr);

    final isAddition = input.startsWith('+');
    final duration = Duration(hours: hours, minutes: minutes);

    return (isAddition, duration);
  }
}
```